# Attaching VS Code to a dockerized django app and running the debugger, where are the docker logs?

Tags: django, docker, visual-studio-code, remote-debugging, docker-logs

I have a dockerized django app which I work on with VS Code.
I start the container, then attach to it using VS Code's remote attach. [image: ``]

Then I start the debugger on port 7000 with the following launch file.

I run the code that crashes things, but its a silent failure in the Terminal / Output / Debug Console. I inspect the docker logs but I only see output from the program running on port 8000.

How do I see the stack trace (or docker logs) for the code running on port 7000?

[image]